# How to apply file naming conventions for SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-server

We are moving file server document to SharePoint online, we found files in file server doesn't have a unified file name/poor file naming. Now, we want to apply file naming convention standards before or after moved to SharePoint. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint recommended file naming convention works based on the file metadata. So based on the source file share folder structure - create the corresponding custom file metadata (content type along with the custom column). Let's say, if you have created **Document ID**, **Document Type**, **Document Name**, and so on. Then standard document naming should be like **Document ID_Document Type_Document Name**, even you can shorten the name like take first chars of each category.

After creating the target document library along with the content type configuration - do the file share migration using some third-party tools like ShareGate, Metalogix, etc.

**Post Migration activity:**

Then develop a site workflow or PowerShell which will rename the file after the migration as per the above-recommended format.

Notes:

- If you want to do straight forward mapping of file name without much calculation you can even configure this in the migration tool, file name mapping property section.
- Even you can rename the file in the file share itself before the migration, then do the migration.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "create the corresponding custom file metadata (content type along with the custom column)"?

Comment: Hi - What I meant was - analyze your source folder structure, based on the files and folder in the source categorized your source into multiple categories, then based on the category create the content type  in the SharePoint site and based on the folder name for those categories create sites columns in the site add to the respective CT, then add the content type to the document library - when we are redesing the SharePoint we should not go with folder based migration which might extend to n level of nested artchituere, so we should avoid the folder based migration.

Comment: If it is not possible to transfer all folder-based architect to CT based - you can keep all data to root level folder and all nested level documents also keep under the root level folder - and those will be identified based on the metadata (content type - site column).